# Serving millions of routes with good performance

Tags: performance, routes, bigdata

I'm doing some research for a new project, for which the constraints and specifications have yet to be set. One thing that is wanted is a large number of paths, directly under the root domain. This could ramp up to millions of paths. The paths don't have a common structure or unique parts, so I have to look for exact matches.

Now I know it's more efficient to break up those paths, which would also help in the path lookup. However I'm researching the possibility here, so bear with me.

I'm evaluating methods to accomplish this, while maintaining excellent performance. I thought of the following methods:

- Storing the paths in an SQL database and doing a lookup on every request. This seems like the worst option and will definitely not be used.
- Storing the paths in a key-value store like Redis. This would be a lot better, and perform quite well I think (have to benchmark it though).
- Doing string/regex matching - like many frameworks do out of the box - for this amount of possible matches is nuts and thus not really an option. But I could see how doing some sort of algorithm where you compare letter-by-letter, in combination with some smart optimizations, could work.

But maybe there are tools/methods I don't know about that are far more suited for this type of problem. I could use any tips on how to accomplish this though.

Oh and in case anyone is wondering, no this isn't homework.

---

**UPDATE**

I've tested the Redis approach. Based on two sets of keywords, I got 150 million paths. I've added each of them using the `set` command, with the value being a serialized string of id's I can use to identify the actual keywords in the request. (`SET 'keyword1-keyword2' '<serialized_string>'`)

A quick test in a local VM with a data set of one million records returned promising results: benchmarking 1000 requests took 2ms on average. And this was on my laptop, which runs tons of other stuff.

Next I did a complete test on a VPS with 4 cores and 8GB of RAM, with the complete set of 150 million records. This yielded a database of 3.1G in file size, and around 9GB in memory. Since the database could not be loaded in memory entirely, Redis started swapping, which caused terrible results: around 100ms on average.

Obviously this will not work and scale nice. Either each web server needs to have a enormous amount of RAM for this, or we'll have to use a dedicated Redis-routing server. I've read [an article](http://instagram-engineering.tumblr.com/post/12202313862/storing-hundreds-of-millions-of-simple-key-value-pairs) from the engineers at Instagram, who came up with a trick to decrease the database size dramatically, but I haven't tried this yet. Either way, this does not seem the right way to do this. Back to the drawing board.

Comment: Even though I've read this several times, I'm not really getting where you think the issue will be with performance. You want to lookup a path like "abc/def/xyz" and do something with it? Wouldnt just hashing the path to speed lookup be fast enough, especially as there is only a few million, or is there something more involved? Once you lookup the path what do you want to do, or do you need to fit in small memory, etc? Maybe add tag algorithm also?

Comment: The paths are all 1 level deep, eg: domain.com/path1/, domain.com/tag-othertag/, domain.com/tag-keyword/. The paths will exist based on a permutation of a couple of collections of keywords, some of which will have thousands of entries. In a nested path such as your example, 3 quick queries with a unique key would be enough. But in this case it would be a query in a table with millions of keys. Therein lies the performance issue.

Comment: What are the possible/typical values associated with your paths/keys? (I mean value as in "key-value-pair", not as in "How do your keys look like?")

Comment: The keys are url-slugs, composed of 1 or 2 tags (like the ones on this site for example). The values will probably be some sort of hash or other notation to link the keys to their corresponding id's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Storing the paths in an SQL database and doing a lookup on every request. This seems like the worst option and will definitely not be used.

You're probably underestimating what a database can do. Can I invite you to reconsider your position there?

For Postgres (or MySQL w/ InnoDB), a million entries is a notch above tiny. Store the whole path in a field, add an index on it, vacuum, analyze. Don't do nutty joins until you've identified the ID of your key object, and you'll be fine in terms of lookup speeds. Say a few ms when running your query from psql.

Your real issue will be the bottleneck related to disk IO if you get material amounts of traffic. The operating motto here is: the less, the better. Besides the basics such as installing APC on your php server, using Passenger if you're using Ruby, etc:

1. Make sure the server has plenty of RAM to fit that index.
2. Cache a reference to the object related to each path in memcached.
3. If you can categorize all routes in a dozen or so regex, they might help by allowing the use of smaller, more targeted indexes that are easier to keep in memory. If not, just stick to storing the (possibly trailing-slashed) entire path and move on.
4. Worry about misses. If you've a non-canonical URL that redirects to a canonical one, store the redirect in memcached without any expiration date and begone with it.
5. Did I mention lots of RAM and memcached?
6. Oh, and don't overrate that ORM you're using, either. Chances are it's taking more time to build your query than your data store is taking to parse, retrieve and return the results.
7. RAM... Memcached...

To be very honest, Reddis isn't so different from a SQL + memcached option, except when it comes to memory management (as you found out), sharding, replication, and syntax. And familiarity, of course.

Your key decision point (besides excluding iterating over more than a few regex) ought to be how your data is structured. If it's highly structured with critical needs for atomicity, SQL + memcached ought to be your preferred option. If you've custom fields all over and obese EAV tables, then playing with Reddis or CouchDB or another NoSQL store ought to be on your radar.

In either case, it'll help to have *lots* of RAM to keep those indexes in memory, and a memcached cluster in front of the whole thing will never hurt if you need to scale.

Comment: Fair point. Maybe I discarded MySQL to quickly. The data is mostly read-only, as there will be very few changes to it. I was (and still am) concerned about scaling and high load when it comes to an RDBMS, but with a K/V store in front of it, maybe it's not so bad. I prefer Redis over Memcached though, but that's interchangeable of course. Redis also has a LRU expiration algorithm that may come in handy here. Anyway, awesome tip, thanks!

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, no memory-based SQL store beats memcached when it comes to clustering support, and memcached uses LRU to decide which keys to drop from the cache when it fills up its memory allotment.

Comment: For scaling and high load, it really isn't a problem if you pick the right database engine. Postgres is very good, fwiw. Skype (yes, that Skype) is running on top of Postgres. MySQL requires a competent babysitter, but is not bad either if you avoid MyISAM tables. (in the prior comment: s/no memory-based SQL/no memory-based NoSQL/)

Answer (score 1):

Redis is your best bet I think. SQL would be slow and regular expressions from my experience are always painfully slow in queries.

I would do the following steps to test Redis:

1. Fire up a Redis instance either with a local VM or in the cloud on something like EC2.
2. Download a dictionary or two and pump this data into Redis. For example something from here: http://wordlist.sourceforge.net/ Make sure you normalize the data. For example, always lower case the strings and remove white space at the start/end of the string, etc.
3. I would ignore the hash. I don't see the reason you need to hash the URL? It would be impossible to read later if you wanted to debug things and it doesn't seem to "buy" you anything. I went to http://www.sha1-online.com/, and entered `ryan` and got `ea3cd978650417470535f3a4725b6b5042a6ab59` as the hash. The original text would be much smaller to put in RAM which will help Redis. Obviously for longer paths, the hash would be better, but your examples were very small. =)
4. Write a tool to read from Redis and see how well it performs.
5. Profit!

Keep in mind that Redis needs to keep the entire data set in RAM, so plan accordingly.

Comment: This was my preferred approach also. See the updated question for my results.

Comment: I just read an article about a team that uses Redis as their primary data store. They have some tips and tricks that might help. https://moot.it/blog/technology/redis-as-primary-datastore-wtf.html

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using some kind of key-value store (i.e. a hashing store), possibly along with hashing the key so it is shorter (something like SHA-1 would be OK IMHO).

Comment: This is my best guess also, as stated in the question. Do you have any experience or live data which can confirm this?